Прописать некоторые параметры для всех потоков
ffmpeg -i {file} \
   -c:v libaom-av1 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
   -map 0:v:0 -filter:v:0 {crop},scale=-2:144,setsar=sar=1/1,fps=50 \
   -map 0:v:0 -filter:v:1 {crop},scale=-2:240,setsar=sar=1/1,fps=50 \ 
   -map 0:v:0 -filter:v:2 {crop},scale=-2:360,setsar=sar=1/1,fps=50 \
   .....

Возможно прописать глобально некоторые параметры для всех видеопотоков.
К примеру, чтобы каждый раз не прописывать
-filter:v:0 {crop},setsar=sar=1/1,fps=50

Прописать один раз, назначить данный фильтр для всех потоков + объединить с фильтром что у потока. К примеру у каждого потока, своя высота кадра. Но кроп/фпс/setsar, у всех идентичен...
setsar=sar=1/1 Ругается, не удается прописать для каждого видеопотока...
Conflicting stream aspect ratios values in Adaptation Set 1. Please ensure all adaptation sets have the same aspect ratio
[out#0/dash @ 0x558afdf4b9c0] Could not write header (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
[vf#0:1 @ 0x558afdf76d40] Error sending frames to consumers: Invalid argument
[vf#0:1 @ 0x558afdf76d40] Task finished with error code: -22 (Invalid argument)
[vf#0:1 @ 0x558afdf76d40] Terminating thread with return code -22 (Invalid argument)

